# How do i calculate the intersection distance between the wedge shape and the ray in 3d space

Tags: c++, raycasting, raytracing

I try to find the ray intersection distance , `t`  with the wedge shape, I checked the intersection for each finite plane of the wedge, I have this solution but is not working as I expect, I get the wrong result, I need help.
[image: The ray intersection distance of the wedge]

```cpp
double getIntersectionDistance(Vec3 origin, Vec3 direction) {
        //Vec3-3d vector of double
        //origin and direction are ray origin and direction respectively.
    /*
    * BackfaceNormal(1, 0, 0)
    * BottomfaceNormal(0, 1, 0)
    * DiagonalNormal(1, 1, 0)
    * RightTriangle(0, 0, 1)
    * LeftTriangle(0, 0, -1)
    */
    if(origin.x < 0) {
        origin.x = -origin.x;
        direction.x = -direction.x;
    }
    if(origin.y < 0) {
        origin.y = -origin.y;
        direction.y = -direction.y;
    }
    if(origin.z < 0) {
        origin.z = -origin.z;
        direction.z = -direction.z;
    }
        
    //for bottom plane
    {
        Vec3 normal(0, 1, 0);
        double ty = (-1 - origin.y) / direction.y;
        double y = origin.y + ty * direction.y;
        if(std::abs(y) <= 1.0 && ty > 0) {
            return ty;
        }
    }
    //for back plane
    {
        Vec3 normal(1, 0, 0);
        double tx = (-1 - origin.x) / direction.x;
        double x = origin.x + tx * direction.x;
        if(std::abs(x) <= 1.0 && tx > 0) {
            return tx;
        }
    }
    //left triangle
    {
        Vec3 normal(0, 0, 1);
        double tz = (-1 - origin.z) / direction.z ;
        double z = origin.z + tz * direction.z;
        if(std::abs(z) <= 1.0 && tz > 0) {
            return tz;
        }
    }
    //right triangle
    {
        Vec3 normal(0, 0, -1);
        double tz = (1 - origin.z) / direction.z;
        double z = origin.z + tz * direction.z;
        if(std::abs(z) <= 1.0  && tz > 0) {
            return tz;
        }
    }
    //diagonal
    Vec3 normal(1, 1, 0);
    const double dn = direction.x + direction.y;
    double txy = (-origin.x - origin.y) / dn;
    double x = origin.x + txy * direction.x;
    double y = origin.y + txy * direction.y;
    if(x + y <= 0.0 && txy > 0) {
        return txy;
    }
    return std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();//no intersection.
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's meant by "the back face(x-axis) of the wedge."  What is "the wedge"?  Also the x-axis is a line, whereas a face would be a two-dimensional region.

Comment: I request an mspaint drawing.

Comment: Floating point math is not exact, so you shouldn't rely on `== 0` giving you the expected answer here. Also, intersection with a plane is not the same as intersection with a rectangle or triangle in that plane.